# Laravel Database Seeding Error TypeError Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Thanks for reading. I am trying to seed my database in laravel. When I ran "php artisan migrate:fresh --seed" command, only the database refreshing part was successful. I have already checked database user authentication, migration types and seeder types, and also models as well. I am simply just trying to seed one table, "chat_rooms". My app is laravel with Jetstream setup, so maybe that is the problem why? I am not sure. But here are my model, migration, and seeder. Please let me know what I can do.

ChatRoom.php model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class ChatRoom extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function messages(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChatMessage::class);
    }
}
class ChatRoom extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function messages(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChatMessage::class);
    }
}
```

chat_rooms_table.php migration file

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('chat_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('chat_rooms');
    }
};
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call([[
            ChatRoomSeeder::class,
        ]]);
    }
}
```

Error Output

> ```
>   INFO  Seeding database.  
>
>
>    TypeError 
>
>   Illegal offset type in isset or empty
>
>   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1324
>     1320▕      * @return string
>     1321▕      */
>     1322▕     public function getAlias($abstract)
>     1323▕     {
>   ➜ 1324▕         return isset($this->aliases[$abstract])
>     1325▕                     ? $this->getAlias($this->aliases[$abstract])
>     1326▕                     : $abstract;
>     1327▕     }
>     1328▕ 
>
>       +3 vendor frames 
>
>   4   database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:16
>       Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call()
>       +34 vendor frames 
>
>   39  artisan:37
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
> ```

Comment: instead of ``[[ ChatRoomSeeder::class, ]]`` pass within a sinle array block as: ``[ ChatRoomSeeder::class, ]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in the data passed in the `call` method of the DatabaseSeeder.php. It should not be an array inside an array. Per Doc, [Calling Additional Seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/seeding#calling-additional-seeders)

So your code block should look like

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call([
            ChatRoomSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing an array with the seeder class name, you should directly provide the class name without enclosing it in another array.

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call(ChatRoomSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is possible to do like what OP did but the issue for the OP was using an array inside the array.

Comment: you can pass all your classes within an array block, it's just that the OP has passed multi dim array which caused the problem!

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It was just a silly mistake syntax mistake by me.